# bsearch optimization in ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-search

I have a method that will search for the first appearance of a number in a sorted array and return the index of that number.

```
def binary_search_sorted(sorted_array, n)
  first = 0
  array.bsearch do |x|
    if x <= n
      first = array.find_index(n)
      break
    else
      first = -1
    end
  end
  p first
end

binary_search_sorted([1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,9], 5)
```

The above will return 6 because the first appearance of 5 is at index 6

Is this the correct use of bsearch? What is actually going on beneath the hood of this method. How could I improve the method?

Comment: If `arr = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,9]` you can also do `arr.bsearch_index { |i|  i == 5 } #=> 6`

Answer (score 1):

Say we are playing "guess the number". I have a number between 0 and 1000 in my mind, you have to guess it. I'll reply either "too low", "too high" or "that's it".
A naive approach would be: "Is it 0?" ("too low"), "Is it 1? " etc. Much faster would be: "Is it 500?" ("too low") ; "Is it 750?" etc.

Which is exactly what `bsearch` does. It's fast, but it will only work on sorted arrays. It returns the object it looks for however, not its index. To retrieve the index, the example uses `find_index`, which uses the naive approach (Is it at index 0? Is it at index 1? etc.), which could have been done without going smart with `bsearch` in the first place. So no, this is not the correct use of `bsearch`. As sagarpandya82 comments, have a look at `bsearch_index`, which will return an index.